# Differential Equations; Bernoulli equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stuck on the following Bernoulli equation,

$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{1}{4t\ln(t)}$ $x(t)=\frac{t^3}{\ln(t)}$ $x(t)^5$

I have changed it to a first order linear equation

$\frac{dz}{dt}-\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}$ $z=\frac{-4t^3}{\ln(t)}$

Where $z=\frac{1}{x^4}$ and $\frac{dz}{dt}=-4\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{1}{x^5}$

I am now solving using an integrating factor of $\ln(t)$ however I am stuck here. I think I have made a mistake getting to this point as it appears to be unsolvable.

If someone could find my mistake or suggest another way of solving that would be great

Comment: Are you trying an integrating factor of $\ln(t)$, or of $1/\ln(t)$?

Comment: I wonder if there is an error.  If it had been $\frac{dx}{dt}\mathbf{-}\frac1{4t\ln(t)}x(t)=\frac{t^3}{\ln(t)}x(t)^5$, then the solution would have been expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x'+\frac{1}{4t\ln(t)}x=\frac{t^3}{\ln(t)}x^5$$
Substitute $z=\frac 1 {x^4}$
$$-z'/4+\frac{1}{4t\ln(t)}z=\frac{t^3}{\ln(t)}$$
$$-z'+\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}z=4\frac{t^3}{\ln(t)}$$
$$(\frac{z}{\ln t})'=-\frac {4{t^3}}{\ln^2 t}$$
$$\frac{z}{\ln t}=-\int \frac {4{t^3}}{\ln^2 t}dt$$
$$z(t)=- \ln t\int \frac {4{t^3}}{\ln^2 t}dt$$
$$\frac 1 {x^4(t)}=- \ln t\int \frac {4{t^3}}{\ln^2 t}dt$$

You can't integrate the last integral with elementary functions

Comment: Although proceeding from $-z'+\frac1{t\ln(t)}z$ to $(\frac z{\ln t})'$ seems to be the part that was causing OP difficulty.

Comment: Maybe @Teepeemm I thought it was the fact that the final integral cant be expressed without Exponential or log integral

Comment: @Isham it was the fact the final integral cant be expressed easily which lead to me questioning the use of an integrating factor and my application of the method. Thanks

Comment: @B.L That's what I thought since you need special functions to integrate it... It happens sometimes that you cant express an integral with elementary functions

Answer (score 4):

You are correct . Now find the integrating factor and continue.

you have  $\frac {dz}{dt } -\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}z = \frac{-4t^3}{\ln(t)}$

the integrating factor IF = $\large e^{\int\frac{-1}{t\ln(t)}\,dt}$

there let $\ln(t) =w\implies \frac1{t}\,dt = dw$

IF=$\large e^{\int\frac{-1}{w}\,dw}  = \large e^{-\ln(w)}=\large e^{-\ln(\ln(t))}= \large e^{\ln(\frac{1}{\ln(t)})}= \frac{1}{\ln(t)}$

the solution is given by ;

$z\cdot \frac{1}{\ln(t)}=\int\frac{-4t^3}{\ln(t)}\cdot \frac{1}{\ln(t)}\,dt$

Can you continue from here?

EDIT : see @Isham s answer if you want to know about the last part.

Comment: I like the way you leave OP to fight the non-elementary solution appearing in the last step. :)

Comment: Thank you :) feels good to be appreciated XD

Comment: it's $t^3$ and not $t^2$

Comment: oops , thank you . will edit right away

Comment: +1 @pranavB23 yw.....

Comment: @pranavB23 Thanks, i was just a little unsure around the double log appearing in my integrating factor, thanks for the confirmation. it was my poor calculus which lead me to thinking it was wrong.

Comment: @B.L no problem . happy to help. also try not to doubt yourself too often :)